# How to handle Kendo grid checkbox event in Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

[image]

I need to display status column value. when only  the checkbox checked row in kendo grid angular. here the code

```
 <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [navigable]="true" [selectable]="{ mode: 'single' }">
          <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" title="" width="20">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggle(dataItem, 'Discontinued')" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued"/>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Units" [width]="30"></kendo-grid-column>
          
           <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" title="status" [width]="30"></kendo-grid-column>
     </kendo-grid>
```

**TS:**

```
  public toggle(dataItem: any, field: string): void {
  
   dataItem[field] =  'primary';
  }
```

above  primay value need to given statically.
when  unchecked the status value still showing the primary value.
I need display status value only checked when unchecked don't display any value.
please help me

**code sample**
[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-checkbox-toggle-dkbyyq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Have you checked my answer and tried it?

Answer (score 3):

In order to keep it simple and follow the way you implemented it, try to change the `toggle` method like that:

```
public toggle(dataItem: any, field: string): void {
  if (dataItem[field] === 'primary') {
    dataItem[field] =  '';
  }
  else {
    dataItem[field] =  'primary';
  }
}
```

Please find the updated
[code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-checkbox-toggle-sawnhw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
and
[result](https://grid-checkbox-toggle-sawnhw.stackblitz.io)